# Likelihood ratio test proof

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a proof given by my statistics textbook. It's a proof presented in relation to the likelihood ratio test.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i- \mu_0)^2 = \sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)^2+n(\bar x-\mu_0)^2$$

I understand all the steps given, until they jump from

$$\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2 - 2(x_i-\bar x)(\bar x-\mu_0)+(\bar x-\mu^2_0)^2$$

to

$$n(\bar x-\mu_0)^2+\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar x)^2$$

I don't really understand what's happened here. We were told that the middle term goes to zero, but then we're left with $\mu^2_0$ instead of $\mu_0$, and where does the $n$ come from? The summation operator? Some guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: The $n$ comes from the fact that you have $n$ samples $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$. We have $x_{\rm bar} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Comment: I noticed I mistyped something. I was supposed to end up with $\sum(x_i-x_{bar})^2$, not $+$.

If the middle term goes to 0, how do we end up with specifically $\mu_0$ and not $\mu_0^2$ in our term?

Comment: That has to be a typo also. Because $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{\rm bar}-\mu_0^2)^2 = n (x_{\rm bar}-\mu_0^2)^2$ since each term we sum over is the same. My guess is that it should be $(x_{\rm bar}-\mu_0)^2$ in the first equation.

Comment: It's present in both my textbook and my instructor's on-the-board proof. Definitely if we were looking for a term with $\mu_0^2$ this would make a lot of sense, but as far as I can tell this is the correct equation.

Comment: Well it does not make sense going from equation 1 to equation 2 if it's not a typo.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \sum_i \Big( (x_i-\bar x)^2 - 2(x_i-\bar x)(\bar x-\mu_0)+(\bar x-\mu_0)^2 \Big) \\
= {} & \left( \sum_i (x_i-\bar x)^2 \right) - 2 \sum_i \Big( (x_i-\bar x)\overbrace{(\bar x - \mu_0)} \Big)  + \sum_i \overbrace{(\bar x - \mu_0)^2}.
\end{align}
Observe that the two expressions under the $\overbrace{\text{overbraces}}$ do not change as $i$ runs from $1$ to $n$.  Therefore they can be pulled out:
$$
\left( \sum_i (x_i-\bar x)^2 \right) - \left( 2(\bar x - \mu_0) \sum_i (x_i-\bar x) \right) + \left( (\bar x - \mu_0)^2 \sum_i 1 \right)
$$
The third term above is $(\bar x - \mu_0)^2 n$.

The sum in the second term above is $0$: $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x) = 0.$$ (Think about why that is so.)